# Complex SQL substr comparison for dups

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

slightly complex problem here I'd like to solve in SQL:

I have duplicate person records like these:
[image]
Many examples like this where the name was misspelled, so my inbound ETL code didn't detect them as duplicates.

I have a dedupping workflow, that culls suspected duplicates with same first/last names and let's the user collapse them. The query for this page is below:

```
SELECT * FROM
((address
INNER JOIN ((person AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    idperson, last_name, first_name, middle, suffix
FROM
    person
GROUP BY last_name , first_name
HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS b ON (a.first_name = b.first_name)
    AND (a.last_name = b.last_name))
INNER JOIN constituent ON a.constituent_idconstituent = constituent.idconstituent
INNER JOIN constituent_address ON a.constituent_idconstituent = constituent_address.constituent_idconstituent) ON address.idaddress = constituent_address.address_idaddress)
INNER JOIN city ON address.city_idcity = city.idcity)
    INNER JOIN
state ON city.state_idstates = state.idstates
WHERE
a.last_name = 'Cascarano'
ORDER BY a.last_name , a.first_name , a.middle , address.line_1 ASC
```

However, my example above where the first names are spelled differently, isn't caught by this query.

Is there a substring or some other SQL trick I can apply here, to somehow maybe chop up the first_name field and look for, maybe 75% letter match? I know I'm reaching...

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Need more to go with. http://sscce.org

Comment: There are phonetic algorithms that try to represent the sound of a word rather than it's specific spelling.  Soundex is an older one and there is also Metaphone.  For both you should be able to grab implementations for mysql.  However, you might find it easier to work with something like Soundex or Metaphone in another layer (such as a web programming layer).  In any case, i have successfully used metaphone in SQL Server for a similar problem.  In the specific case you cite, however, wouldn't it be easier to add some address dupe detection?

Comment: Thanks Dwight - you're right about using address dup as a method - but that's just for the one example I cited above (they both clearly share the same address record and last name - easy), but I still need some way to identify that one the first names was misspelled - and not just **different**. Many people live in the same household and share a last name - sometimes even a first name (but are father-son, with a different suffix). I think I still need to normalize mispelled names, then compare for equivalence.